# Why do I get a "'documentScan' is not allowed for specified platform" warning?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, applet

Recently Chrome removed all support for applets which is the main cause of my problem. In our web application we are using a third-party applet (Asprise) to include scanning functionality. Currently there are no new updates available from Asprise to overcome the problem. The Chrome API seems to have it's own native scan functionality through the chrome.documentScan method. However, when I attempt to load the extension sample provided [here](https://github.com/orbitbot/chrome-extensions-examples/tree/master/document_scan), I get the following warning when loading the extension.

I am attempting to simply load the directory as an unpacked extension using the developer mode in chrome://extensions. I have tried this on OS X, Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu and I get the same warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in [the official API doc](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/documentScan):

> **Important:** This API works **only on Chrome OS**.